# 25Q128 flash and garbage data over SPI

Tags: spi, flash

I have a logic analyzer coming in the mail, but thought I might ask for help here first.

I soldered the 25Q128 flash onto an adapter and wired it up to an Arduino UNO clone as you can see in the images below. I get nonsense data in the serial monitor. The 4 10k resistors are connected in parallel to GND and there are 4.7k resistors on the SCK, MISO, MOSI and CS lines. I am using the TestFlash sketch from the SPIMemory Arduino library by Marzogh. Could it be a bad soldering joint? Or am I missing something?

I used this as a guide also:

https://www.14core.com/wiring-the-winbond-w25qxx-spi-serial-flash-memory-with-microcontroller/

https://www.14core.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/windbond-spi-flash-memory-W25Q80BV-8bit-storage-wiring-guide.jpg

Here are some pictures and a diagram.

[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsJix.jpg)

[Breadboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxLf0.jpg)

[Closeup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwRGi.jpg)

[Arduino](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9whL5.jpg)

[Fritzing diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkU0u.png)

Comment: That "guide" is bad. You don't want any resistors on MISO. Just connect it direct between the Arduino and the chip.

Answer (score -1):

You will be better to buy one of these from aliExpress.
[image]

here's de pinout connections to an arduino:

- Pin 1 - CS
- Pin 2 - D0 (I/O1)
- Pin 3 - VCC (I/O2)
- Pin 4 - GND
- Pin 5 - Di
- Pin 6 - CLK
- Pin 7 - VCC (I/O)
- Pin 8 - VCC

this connection setup does not make use of the full data parallel async I/O, as you can see only I/O1 is connected to D0. This way has much slower data transfers.

Comment: what is "pin 1"? Uno TX pin?

Comment: CS = chip select

Comment: I ask what are the pins on the left. Uno pins? you use the TX pin as CS?

Comment: you can use any digital pin for CS